# Will this code consume all purchases of managed Items V3 for this user?

Tags: android

I found this code on the web. Do you think that it can actually release my managed items and make them available for purchase again or does it need some modification?  It seems like I'm not able to test it correctly. It looks like I need a test button to release all my managed items. Am I on the right track or totally misguided ? I just need an opinion please you don't have to release your managed items ...

```
 public  void consumeAllOlderItems() {
    Bundle ownedItems = null;
    try {
        ownedItems = mHelper.mService.getPurchases(3, sGame.getContext().getPackageName(), "inapp", null);
    } catch (RemoteException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    int response = ownedItems.getInt("RESPONSE_CODE");

    if (response == 0)
    {
        alertNonStatic("consumeAllOlderItems() google responded ok to our consumables");
        ArrayList<String> ownedSkus = ownedItems.getStringArrayList("INAPP_PURCHASE_ITEM_LIST");
        ArrayList<String> purchaseDataList = ownedItems.getStringArrayList("INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA_LIST");
        ArrayList<String> signatureList = ownedItems.getStringArrayList("INAPP_DATA_SIGNATURE");
        //String continuationToken = ownedItems.getString("INAPP_CONTINUATION_TOKEN");
        if(purchaseDataList != null && purchaseDataList.size() > 0)
        for (int i = 0; i < purchaseDataList.size(); ++i) {
            try {
                String purchaseData = purchaseDataList.get(i);
                JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(purchaseData);
                if(jo != null && jo.length() > 0);
                final String token = jo.getString("purchaseToken");
                String sku = null;
                String sig = null;
                if (ownedSkus != null){
                    sku = ownedSkus.get(i);
                    if (signatureList != null && signatureList.size() > 0){
                         sig = signatureList.get(i);
                    }

                    consume(sku, token, purchaseData,sig);

                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
    else if(response != 0){
        alertNonStatic("Response for older items is "+response);
    }

}



    private  void consume(String sku, String token, String purchaseData,String sig) {
    alertNonStatic("consume is trying to consume an item");
    Purchase purchace = null;
    try {
        purchace = new Purchase("inapp", purchaseData, sig);
    } catch (JSONException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    mHelper.consumeAsync(purchace,mConsumeFinishedListener);

}
```

Comment: So you are going to use code you do not understand for manage purchases, based on opinion of anonymous random people. Impressive :) And of course - go ahead :)

Comment: You could just say "NO or Yes because this is how I would do it" or "Here is how I would do it" .but the above answer .. is not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

There was no reason to re-create purchase object to use consumeAsync since the recomendation on google docs says to spawn a new thread  with this and is over :

int response = mService.consumePurchase(3, getPackageName(), token);